# Database error after DeleteObject(...) / SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

Context: web application / ASP.NET 4.0 / EF 4.0 / MSSQLEXPRESS2012

I'm trying to do a simple delete as follows:

```
if (someObject != null)
{
    if (!context.IsAttached(someObject))
       context.SomeObjects.Attach(someObject);

    context.DeleteObject(someObject);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The code executes without problem and SaveChanges returns the expected number of rows. But when I try to read the table afterwards it times out (this happens in mssms as well as in code).

It also seems to corrupt other processes, returning '8501 MSDTC on server is unavailable' and "No process is on the other end of the pipe" on subsequent site access. Which of the three errors happens in the application seems somewhat random, but the timeout in mssms always happens.

Inserts and updates on the same table execute without problem.

Apart from reading through a zillion posts, I tried wrapping it in try/catch and transaction with SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.None) and manual AcceptAllChanges; the debugger shows the correct object just before delete - everything appears normal until table read or accessing another page.

I suspect somehow the lock is not released, but other objects in different tables successfully delete with the exact same logic. I'm not sure where best to look next - any ideas are greatly appreaciated!

Comment: Are you sharing the context across multiple threads without synchronization?

Comment: thanks for your quick response - the answer is no, but meanwhile i found the answer, although i still don't know why the problem only happened in this particular context

Answer (score 0):

must have made a mistake with transaction before - the following worked:

```
var transactionScope = new TransactionScope
                                    (TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
                                        new TransactionOptions()
                                        {
                                            IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
                                        }
                                    );
        try
        {
            using (transactionScope)
            { ...etc
```

the following link explains more about the whys of explicit transactions
http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2010/06/29/Transactions-and-Connections-in-Entity-Framework-40.aspx

still not sure why it's working without transaction for the other deletes though